# Update core keeping other composer packages

Tags: 8, drush

After upgrading Drupal to the last version with Drush (8.1.15) the other **`composer.json`** dependencies (e.g. drupalconsole) are removed.

Are there any way to update Drupal with Drush keeping other composer dependencies?

```
diff --git a/docroot/composer.json b/docroot/composer.json
index 6089861..b9536cf 100644
--- a/docroot/composer.json
+++ b/docroot/composer.json
@@ -4,28 +4,11 @@
     "type": "project",
     "license": "GPL-2.0+",
     "require": {
-        "ckeditor/fakeobjects": "4.6.2",
-        "ckeditor/image": "4.6.2",
-        "ckeditor/link": "4.6.2",
-        "codemirror/codemirror": "5.27.4",
         "composer/installers": "^1.0.24",
-        "drupal/console": "~1.0",
-        "jquery/geocomplete": "1.7.0",
-        "jquery/icheck": "1.0.2 ",
-        "jquery/image-picker": "0.3.0",
-        "jquery/inputmask": "3.3.7",
-        "jquery/intl-tel-input": "12.0.0",
-        "jquery/rateit": "1.1.1",
-        "jquery/select2": "4.0.3",
-        "jquery/timepicker": "1.11.11 ",
-        "jquery/toggles": "4.0.0",
-        "jquery/word-and-character-counter": "2.5.1",
-        "progress-tracker/progress-tracker": "1.4.0",
-        "signature_pad/signature_pad": "2.3.0",
-        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "~1.4"
+        "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^1.4"
     },
     "replace": {
-        "drupal/core": "~8.3"
+        "drupal/core": "^8.4"
     },
     "minimum-stability": "dev",
     "prefer-stable": true,
```

I've seen that there is a composer project for Drupal but I'm not using it in this project.

Comment: "I've seen that there is a composer project for Drupal but I'm not using it in this project." ... then start.

Comment: @IvanJaros How you can you start using drupal.project on an already started project?

Comment: Just follow the instructions in here https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project and then copy your sites directory in it.

Comment: Probably because it overwrote the composer.json file with whats on Drupal.org. Ivan is correct, you would need to use a Composer favoring solution like Drupal Project or Acquia BLT where this would not happen.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a composer based project, you probably should use composer to update it.  E.g.:

composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies

Make sure to keep the composer.json, composer.lock, and docroot/vendor/composer/installed.json files in your repository.

Note:  It's best to go 'all-in' with composer and use it to add and maintain modules as well as core. E.g.:

Add new module:   composer require drupal/module

Update module:  composer update drupal/module --with-dependencies

To manage patches, see the cweagans/composer-patches project.

You can also include various 3rd party libraries (e.g. chosen, colorbox, and the like) using your composer.json file.

Comment: I believe what the OP is asking about is a composer.json file that was overwritten during a core update, and losing all that information - not how to use Composer.